# Can I programmatically tell if Spotlight is enabled?

Tags: macos, cocoa, spotlight

I'm using the Spotlight API (NSSMetadataQuery) in my application.  I want to display a helpful note to the user if they try to do something that would do a Spotlight query on a volume which isn't indexed.

I can determine this in a terminal by running "mdutil -s /Volumes/Foo".

Is there an API which returns this information, that doesn't require running an external program?

Answer (score 1):

Seems as though there's neither a documented method or written solution out there. [The same question has been asked before to no avail on Apple's Mailing List](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/215728-checking-whether-spotlight-indexing-is-enabled-for-volume.html), so I guess [using `NSTask` and parsing the output](https://gist.github.com/sebj/dd62489a083507123f39/raw/363a8ce8083d4cb9b8f66f9b217f14810c528ad8/gistfile1.m) (my rough sample code linked) would be one way to go about getting this information from a Cocoa app/programatically.